# Where does Microsoft Word store autorecovered documents in Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, microsoft

I can't seem to find the Autorecovery Save folder in Catalina. Previously I used a command line string to see the files, but that command doesn't work anymore.

Is this feature still implemented with Word using O365 subscription and macOS 10.15.1 Catalina?

Comment: They used to be at this path: `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Library/Preferences/AutoRecovery` . I don't have Word installed on my Mac to verify, but I have this in my notes.

Comment: Thank you for editing my post, but I don't have an O365 subscription—I have a downloaded copy of Word for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the AutoRecovery folder under the Library of your user folder.

- The library under your user folder is normally hidden. So press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to see all the hidden folder.

After this, go to

```
/Macintosh HD/Users/xxx/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Library/Preferences/AutoRecovery
```

*Here xxx is your username*

You will see your recovered files over there.

Comment: It doesn't take me to the folder, it takes me to the "What Are Relocated Items?" page. I don't have an O365 subscription—that was edited into my comment by an admin. I have a downloaded copy of Microsoft Office for Mac.

Comment: aka ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Library/Preferences/AutoRecovery